# How to use concurrent.futures in Python scraping

Tags: python-3.x, multithreading, python-multiprocessing, python-multithreading, concurrent.futures

I'm struggling to get multithreading/multiprocessing working in Python. This is python file that i have. I have this piece of code setup. The scrape function scrapes a website https://satudata.kemendag.go.id/balance-of-trade-with-trade-partner-country, it scrapes data from many country which I put on xlsx file:

```
import json
import pandas as pd
import copy
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

def getBalanceofTrade():
    cookies = {
        '_ga': 'GA1.3.672481365.1630462756',
        'sc_is_visitor_unique': 'rx12421317.1631602001.FE09E031FA464FEEAD095B438DD92829.2.2.2.2.2.2.2.2.2',
        '_ga_41205092': 'GS1.1.1631601995.2.0.1631602551.0',
        'varient_csrf_cookie': 'c34f577f894740d92106453d293f69b4',
        'ci_session': 'q9qvice0p2dgnp5f50veghgrqeveavrm',
        '_gid': 'GA1.3.542540031.1635307774',
        '_gat_gtag_UA_155890962_1': '1',
        'f5avr0338662302aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa_cspm_': 'DMPCJNDKGKPBLIDLCKDBLLDGAEPJPBKDHBPPMIDGKFDEMKGDHFNEBJBDOLAMKFJACFDCDGKEHKFEFIPPNNKAJEACAPLNMFADDKOEHBJBKJGGDMKBNHHFMJBOEGLPMEPA',}

    headers = {
        'Connection': 'keep-alive',
        'sec-ch-ua': '"Chromium";v="94", "Google Chrome";v="94", ";Not A Brand";v="99"',
        'Accept': 'application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01',
        'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8',
        'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest',
        'sec-ch-ua-mobile': '?0',
        'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/94.0.4606.81 Safari/537.36',
        'sec-ch-ua-platform': '"Windows"',
        'Origin': 'https://satudata.kemendag.go.id',
        'Sec-Fetch-Site': 'same-origin',
        'Sec-Fetch-Mode': 'cors',
        'Sec-Fetch-Dest': 'empty',
        'Referer': 'https://satudata.kemendag.go.id/balance-of-trade-with-trade-partner-country',
        'Accept-Language': 'en-US,en;q=0.9',}
    
    base_params = {
        'varient_csrf_token': 'c34f577f894740d92106453d293f69b4',
        'category': 'country'}
    
    value_id = pd.read_excel('Value ID Countries.xlsx')
    value_dict = dict(zip(value_id['VALUE ID'], value_id['COUNTRY']))
    
    params_list = []
    
    for key, value in value_dict.items():
        new_params = copy.copy(base_params)
        new_params['region_id'] = key
        params_list.append(new_params)
    df_all = pd.DataFrame()
    
    for params in params_list:
        response = requests.post('https://satudata.kemendag.go.id/balance-query', headers=headers, cookies=cookies, data=params)
        json_data = json.loads(response.text)
        df1 = pd.json_normalize(json_data)
        #print(df1)
        table_list = df1['data']
        for table in table_list:
            df = pd.DataFrame.from_records(table)
            df_all = df_all.append(df, ignore_index=True)
            
    country = []
    for i in value_id['COUNTRY']:
        x = [i] * len(df)
        country.append(x)
        
    country_list = [item for s in country for item in s]
    
    df_all['Country'] = country_list
    
    df_new = df_all.iloc[:, 0:6]
    df_new1 = df_all.iloc[:, 8:9]
    df_new2 = df_all.iloc[:, 10:11]
    result = pd.concat([df_new, df_new1, df_new2], axis=1)
    
    URL = 'https://satudata.kemendag.go.id/balance-of-trade-with-trade-partner-country'
    page = requests.get(URL)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')
    table =soup.find('table', id="table-balance")
    rows = table.find_all('th')
    cols = [item.text.strip() for item in rows]
     #column name uraian
    column_name = [cols[0]]
    column_name1 = cols[1:6]
    column_name2 = [cols[10]]
    tahun = column_name1 + column_name2
    final_column = column_name + column_name1 + column_name2 + ['Country']
    result.columns = final_column
    
    desc_1 = 3*(result['Uraian'][0],)
    desc_2 = 3*(result['Uraian'][3],)
    desc_3 = 3*(result['Uraian'][6],)
    desc_4 = 3*(result['Uraian'][9],)
    x = desc_1 + desc_2 + desc_3 + desc_4
    y = list(x)
    z = y * len(value_id['COUNTRY'])
    result = result.replace(['TOTAL PERDAGANGAN', 'EKSPOR', 'IMPOR', 'NERACA PERDAGANGAN'], ['Total', 'Total', 'Total', 'Total']) 
    df2 = pd.DataFrame(z, columns=['description'])
    
    result = result.rename(columns = {'Uraian': 'tipe'}, inplace = False)
    table = pd.concat ([df2, result], axis=1)
    
    df_table = table.melt(id_vars=['description', 'tipe', 'Country'], value_vars=tahun, var_name='year')
    
    return(df_table)
```

But i don't know what to do next. I'll gladly accept any help, it's my first time working with concurrent stuff in python

Comment: Please provide a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) including relevant data as well as your actual and expected outputs.

Comment: The expected output is the same as the output in the code, but I want the process to run faster @JanWilamowski

Comment: What have you tried so far? Which part precisely do you want to parallelize? Have you had a look at [multiprocessing.Pool](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)?

Comment: I didnt know how to parallelizing requests @JanWilamowski

Comment: The same way you parallelize anything else. I realized that I put the wrong link to [multiprocessing.Pool](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.pool.Pool) in my last comment but it seems like you should start with a basic tutorial for that.